# is it posible to create Web Bot in delphi?

Tags: delphi, web-crawler

i was just curious about [webbot project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Bot) and i wish that i could create something similar to that project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly are welcome to try to do so... but please be aware that you're going to spend years learning a lot of linguistics and sources of syntactic ambiguity along the way.

It might be easier to look at things from a different perspective... write a set of programs to analyze predictions made by various bloggers, and to keep track of how accurate they turn out to be. The key is to make it an automated process, and not something which would be subject to your own personal biases.

Once you have a few years of data processed, you'll know who has a good handle on the future, and who is blowing smoke.

Delphi is just as good a choice for pulling data across the net as any other system.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, there's no reason such a thing couldn't be written in Delphi. Given how secretive they are about their methods, algorithms, etc., the practicality of attempting to duplicate their work (regardless of language) is probably open to considerable question.